# How to run inline script AFTER jquery confirmed as defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I'm working under particular circumstances and I am trying to get a slick slider carousel to run.

I get an error that `$ is not defined.`

Unless I use

```
window.onload = function(e){
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-slick').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 5000,
      dots: true,
      fade: true,
      speed: 1000
    });
  });
};
```

The problem is, this slider is the first thing on the page, so I can not wait until everything is loaded, as it takes way too long.

I cannot change the order of my script tag or make sure the jQuery link is properly placed in the head an so on.

I know that other sliders on the page work just fine, and I also know that this particular one works fine once the proper files are loaded

There must be a way to check if `$` is defined, keep checking until it is, and then run the script once confirmed.

Comment: I've tried this multiple times and it still does not seem work. It is already  referenced far earlier in the `head` tag anyway, thanks for the reply

Comment: What bothers me is the *"I cannot change the order of my script tag or make sure the jQuery link is properly placed in the head an so on"* part. Why? You clearly *can* change *something*. Order is crucial in JS. If you're loading your code using a `<script>` tag than have you tried to add the `defer` attribute? Such will make sure your script is executed once the DOM is parsed. Using an aggressive interval/loop would be odd...

Comment: You could explain a bit better the following: Does the slider already uses jQuery? Where is it placed? Where is jQuery placed? Why your script tags are not right before the closing `</body>` tag but rather in a render-blocking manner - in the head of your document? Do you have control over the hosting page or you have an *[XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)* problem?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, I've tried the `defer` attribute. I'm forced to edit the source code of a text widget of an uncommon cms. This places the code at the bottom of a rather long page. I'm not sure why I can't just reference jquery just before, I think I'm doing something wrong. The slider does use jquery and it's all placed in the head, which I don't have access to

Comment: Just wondering if your jQuery goes in compatibility mode (works wordpress pages when you need an inline code)? If so, you can try to wrap the statement 
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { // your code });

Comment: @vsevolodts unfortunately no. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timer = setInterval(checkjQuery, 5000);

function checkjQuery() {
  if(window.jQuery) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    callSlick();
    console.log('jQuery is loaded');
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('waiting');
  }
}

function callSlick() {
  $('.js-slick').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 5000,
      dots: true,
      fade: true,
      speed: 1000
    });
};
```

Similar to DanDavis solution

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens on the page if the net hiccups and jquery doesn't load? Does it freeze the browser up due to the looping?

Answer (score 1):

use a waiter:

```
setTimeout(function wait(){
 if(!window.$) return setTimeout(wait, 100);

 // do stuff needing $ here:
 console.info("$=", $);
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO the answer from @dandavis solves the issue the simplest.

I'd like to offer a way to make a simple "wait-er" re-usable and show how to integrate this with the code you shared.

A re-usable wait-er:

```
function waitUntil(getResource, callback) {
  // Copied from @dandavis' answer
  setTimeout(function wait() {
    const resource = getResource();
    if(!resource) return setTimeout(wait, 100);

    callback(resource);
  }, 100);
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  waitUntil(function () { return window.$; }, function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.js-slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        dots: true,
        fade: true,
        speed: 1000
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Or if you wanted to, you could make it promise-based:

```
function waitUntil(getResource) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function wait() {
      const resource = getResource();
      if(!resource) return setTimeout(wait, 100);

      resolve(resource);
    }, 100);
  });
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  waitUntil(function () { return window.$; })
    .then(function () {
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.js-slick').slick({
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 5000,
          dots: true,
          fade: true,
          speed: 1000
        });
      });
    });
};
```